# how to fix pyomo conflict constraint?

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am using the pyomo for my thesis project and working on MILP model.
I have an objective function which is to minimise the late arrival of certain goods to the warehouse and hence I came with an objective function as follows,
[image]

Here, I am unable to program the condition for the "t" as it kept saying pyomo conflict error.
I also tried to change the objective function as
Sum W[itkr]*q[it]*s[kr]
where s[kr] is a decsion variable that is equal to 1 if the vehicle gets back to the depot within a particular time of 180 minutes.

hence, I tried to come write a constratint as follows,
for r in model.R:

expression = sum(model.s[k,r] for k in model.K if model.v[k,r]-180>=0) == 1

but it still responds with a pyomo conflict error. Can someone please help me ? I am unable to complete my thesis and fear not passing.

Thanks a ton

Comment: Hello Vignesh, welcome to SO. Before people can help you, you have to share a bit more. Try to simplify the problem to the smallest possible extent. If you are still getting the error, please post a "reproducible" example, with the error and someone could help you.  I find this very helpful for myself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are unbalanced parentheses in your formula. I.e. it is wrong.

Comment: @RamNarasimhan : Sir, Thank you for the comment, found it useful. I am pretty new to the subject and unable to solve due to the pyomo conflict error. I solved the parenthesis and still face the issue.